# Generic interface and methods issue

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I am currently trying to implement generic interface.

```
public interface IAssociatedTrie<T> 
{
    bool Contains(string key);
    T GetValue(string key);
    void Add(string key, T value);
}
```

I have a class which implements this interface

```
 class Trie<T> : IAssociatedTrie<T>
 {
    //some work

    public void Add(string key, T value)
    {
        //some work
    }
    ...
 }
```

And then I want to pass an instance of class with IAssociatedTrie interface to some method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Trie<int> myTrie = new Trie<int>();
        TestTrie(myTrie);
    }

private static void TestTrie<T>(IAssociatedTrie<T> myTrie) 
    {
        //some work
        myTrie.Add("oa", 3); //error
        //some work
    }
```

But here I get CS1503 error "Can't convert int to T". I found that

```
myTrie.Add("oa", (T)(object)4);
```

fix the issue, but this looks very inelegant and I am preety sure I am doing something wrong. How should I modify method/class method for this to work without parsing to object->T?

Comment: Should `private static void TestTrie<T>(IAssociatedTrie<T> myTrie)` use `int` instead of `T`?

Comment: No, I want it to use type T of Trie<T>, that is being passed as a parameter. Int is just an example.

Comment: But 3 is an `int`. What would you expect to occur if you added it to a `IAssociatedTrie<Guid>`?

Comment: I also tried restraining T to struct, but even this way I couldn't pass int to this method.

Comment: It's really unclear why you would *expect* to be able to add a value of 3 to an *arbitrary* trie. If you want to be able to add an int, make your `TestTrie` method non-generic, and change the parameter type to `IAssociatedTrie<int>`.

Comment: It seems you goal is to have trie of various numeric types (int, long, byte, float and so on). If so - there is unfortunately no way in C# to restrict `T` to numeric types.

Comment: Consider adding `void TryAdd(string key, object value);` and then attempting a cast / convert inside the `TryAdd` method. It is ugly. Also consider, calling `myTrie.Add(` via a `dynamic` temporary variable.

Comment: Trie is a prefix tree

Comment: @Flater trie is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: @Evk isnt Int32 a struct? Then why constraining T to struct doesn't work?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНестеров Int32 is struct, and other numeric types are structs, but there are many structs besides numeric types. For example, `DateTime` is struct, `struct MyStruct {}` is struct. Does it makes sense to add 3 to `MyStruct`? Not much.

Comment: Because while `Int32` is a `struct`, not every `struct` is an `Int32`.

Comment: Well, fair. Thanks guys. I just changed T to int since this method was only for testing purposes (with ints).

Comment: @Evk: My bad. The `TryAdd` mentions in the comments made me think that this was a "try" (= "attempt").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is *generic*. That means your code *must* work for *any* `T`.

Your code adding `3` works *only* for `T` = `int`. What if I call your method with `T` = `Elephant`? There is no way you can cast your `3` into an `Elephant`.

I don't know what you want to *do* exactly. Either using the constant `3` is wrong, or having a generic `T` is wrong. That is a thing only you can decide. But your compiler is correct in flagging this error. You cannot use the constant `3` as a value for a `T`.

Comment: Well, yeah, you are right and I understand that compiler error is preety fair. I was just trying to think about some tricky work-arounds, but I couldn't come up with something better then casting to object and then to T. It looks like the only way to do it, but of course will cause some hypothetical troubles if method would be called with wrong parameters.

Comment: If there is a possibility that your method won't work with a specific `T` I use, please don't make it generic. Use the proper type. If your method only works for `IAssociatedTrie<int>` that's fine. Use `IAssociatedTrie<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

when you say `myTrie.Add("oa", 3);` - I am not sure what is the point of having generic method in first place. However, looks you intended to use something like :

```
private static void TestTrie<T>(IAssociatedTrie<T> myTrie, T value) 
    {
        myTrie.Add("oa", value);
    }
```